# looping cor.test on split data

Tags: loops, split

My small challenge is in the code of a loop I am trying to make of a dataframe that is split to allow correlations for each group

an example of what I need to achieve for each spp

```
rbt<-subset(Trjan,Trjan$Spp=="Redbilled Teal")
cotest<-cor.test(rbt$year,rbt$abundance)
vals<-c(cotest$estimate,cotest$p.value)
```

vals# at the end of the day I need a dataframe with species, slope & p value e.g. "Redbilled Teal" "its slope" "p value"

But because I have many spp I cant do this for all of them.After following some examples I got this code but I am failing to put my variables well.

```
uniq <- unique(unlist(Trjan$Spp))
for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
  data_1 <- subset(Trjan, Spp == uniq[i])
  cor.test(year,abundance)
  vals<-c(estimate,p.value)
}
# error "abundance not found
```

any help. I thought my small problem would not need a sample of data, if need arise I can edit.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got help from a friend, I realised that I needed to create a new empty data frame to store all my cor.test results by species

```
final.tab<-data.frame(Species=character(),cor_est=numeric(),cor_pval=numeric(),stringsAsFactors = F)

uniq <- unique(unlist(Trjan$Spp))
for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
  data_1 <- subset(Trjan, Spp == uniq[i])
  #I had to create an object to store your cor.test results and add the object name (i.e. "data_1$" before your column name)
  cor.test.temp<-cor.test(data_1$year,data_1$abundance)
  vals<-c(as.character(uniq[i]),round(as.numeric(cor.test.temp$estimate),3),round(as.numeric(cor.test.temp$p.value),3))
  #progressively filling in my data.frame with cor.test results
  final.tab[i,]<-vals
}
```